# Event .change not working on IE 11.1198

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, events, internet-explorer-11

I have event `.change` on my website but it's not working when I open my website on IE 11.1198. I have been tried anything but it's still not working.

This is my dropdown select code :

```
<?=form_dropdown('qty',$row['room_amount'], '','class="mb10"
                  data-plan-type="'.$row_rates['data']->plan_type.'" 
                  data-plan-id="'.$row_rates['data']->plan_id.'"
                  data-plan-day="'.$row_rates['data']->plan_day.'"')?>
```

I work this on `codeigniter` framework

This is my `.change` script :

```
<script>
$('select[name="qty"]').change(function() {
    alert("working");
});
</script>
```

I used jQuery v1.10.1

I already tried to use `.click` but it's still not working. I also tried used `.live($.browser.msie?'click':'change', function() { ....` it's still not working. I also tried used `.blur` it's still not working.

Anyone knows how to resolve this ? Many thanks.

Comment: Please define _"not working"_. Also, what does this have to do with php?

Comment: @AluanHaddad as you can see if the trigger is to showing `alert` but the `alert` doesn't showing when `.change` event is triggered

Comment: Does this work? http://samples.msdn.microsoft.com/workshop/samples/author/dhtml/refs/onchangeEX.htm

Comment: @AluanHaddad yes, that's work.

Comment: This doesn't seem PHP relevant.

Comment: Add your markup to the question please. Also, can you confirm that your exact code works correctly in another browser?

Comment: Since it is specific to IE 11 I think this is a client side issue (e.g. no PHP). Adding a https://jsfiddle.net/ the demonstrates the issue might help. I don't have IE so I can't test this.

Comment: @AluanHaddad I have been tried to use `onchange` according to your example and it's still not working on IE but working on Chrome and Mozilla

Comment: Sorry, as @chris85 noted, my answer was not really an answer. However, can you please add your markup? Also, include your jQuery version.

Comment: Do you get any errors in the console? Please confirm that the code shown in the question works as desired in other browsers.

Comment: @nnnnnn nothing show in the console and with other browser this code is works fine.

Comment: @AluanHaddad I used jQuery v1.10.1

Comment: @nnnnnn I used jQuery v1.10.1

Comment: @Antonio can you add the markup please?

Comment: @AluanHaddad Okay

Comment: @Antonio I mean the markup defining the select element.

Comment: @Antonio your code should only run when the document is ready. Try `$(function () { $('select[name="qty"]').change...`

Comment: @AluanHaddad I have been run it on document ready but it's still not working

Comment: Sorry, I don't know anything about that framework. It looks like it should work. What happens if you run the code from the browser console? Does it work?

Comment: @AluanHaddad What do you mean run the code from browser console ?

Comment: F12 => console => paste `$('select[name="qty"]').change(function() {
    alert("working");
});` into the textbox at the bottom. Also, try without jQuery: `document.getElementsByName('qty')[0].onchange = function () { ... }`

Comment: @AluanHaddad The point is `.change` is doesn't work in IE, I already tried many ways. And do you have some suggestion or not ?

Comment: It obviously does work in if it works here http://samples.msdn.microsoft.com/workshop/samples/author/dhtml/refs/onchangeEX.htm and you said it does.

Comment: @AluanHaddad It's working if inside `onchange` is `alert` but if inside `onchange` is `function` it doesn't work. I put `alert` inside `function` which  call in `onchange`

Comment: Sorry, I cannot reproduce. I tried with a local HTML file with IE 11.296 and jQuery 1.10.1 (loaded from a cdn) and it works. Either there is a bug in your specific build of IE or there is more going on than you have indicated.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144406/discussion-between-aluan-haddad-and-antonio).